# How can I upgrade the iOS Firebase SDK?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

Since I upgraded to Xcode 15, my Flutter iOS App does not compile anymore on my M1 Mac. Many people fixed this problem by upgrading Firebase to a version >10.0.0.
However, the `Package.swift` file from the Firebase package in Xcode says `let firebaseVersion = "8.13.0"`, which is quite an old version. Commands like `pod update`etc. did not change this version. Do you have any suggestions on how to upgrade Firebase SDK?

Comment: How are you adding firebase to your flutter project?  Are you using flutterfire? Update that version. You will also need to edit the cocoapods file to tell it to use a newer version.

Comment: The generated Podfile.lock file should provide clues about what is preventing the version update

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to update your `firebase_core` package

```
firebase_core: ^latest_version
```

And then, go to the ios folder and write into the cmd `pod update`

```
cd ios 
pod update
```

and finally,

```
flutter clean
```